# Jenkins build failed after bitbucket drop support of TLS 1.0/1.1

Tags: ssl, jenkins, bitbucket, tls1.2

our Jenkins build failed with this error
Unable to access "https://bitbucket.org/.../xx.git", error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Obviously it is linked to the depreciation of TLS1.1 and 1.0, but I did check the jenkins slave JDK, it is JDK1.8.0.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out my Windows Jenkins node was using git version 1.9. I uninstalled that one and installed the most recent version (2.19.2 at the moment).

You can call `git --version` to get the version your system is using.

Now my Windows Jenkins node is back online and working properly.

Comment: thanks, mate. yeah, same case here, my git version is even older. Still not sure what is the underlying reason, is it the openssl version used by the old git?

Comment: @peanut I imagine it can be that since git for Windows includes the openssl binary, but I really don't know. But it was a good moment to update to the latest version of git.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. I have removed all old versions of git and then install new.